# Does the Common Service Locator support Mono .NET?

Tags: .net, mono, inversion-of-control, common-service-locator

Does the [Common Service Locator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/), used for "providing an abstraction over IoC containers and service locators", support Mono .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does. Please read [this wiki page](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multi-target%20CSL%20binaries) from the CommonServiceLocator project.

Answer (score 1):

From what I read on the project's website, it should work on Mono. Spring, Castle and LinFu are supposed to work fine.

You can try to run [MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) with CSL's binaries to find out. Or, better, you might try to run some example programs in Mono. If they don't work, Mono developers will appreciate a bug report.